# Rolling update without outages when replicas: 1

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

What is the difference when I change `maxUnavailable` with these rolling update strategies:

**Case 1:**

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
      rollingUpdate:
         maxSurge: 1
         maxUnavailable: 0
```

**Case 2:**

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
      rollingUpdate:
         maxSurge: 1
         maxUnavailable: 1
```

The first case is easy to understand, but what will happen in the second case?

Additionally, to ensure there no downtime/outages during app updates or by Kubernetes nodes auto scale/auto maintenance process, is config `replicas must >= 2` mandatory?

Comment: If you omit `strategy:` altogether, the default behavior will be to create a second Pod, wait for it to become ready, and then terminate the first one.  (This is pretty easy to observe with `kubectl get pod -w`.)  The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment) suggests the last case, with `maxUnavailable` equal to `replicas`, allows the cluster to tear down the old Pods first.

Comment: Hi `NothingCtrl` is your issue resolved.. revert back here so that we can assist you if you are having any other issues.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni is ok, I just want to clarify between two configs

Answer (score 0):

**The first case is easy to understand, but what will happen in the second case?**

When you specify both `maxSurge` and `maxUnavailable` at the sametime, this defines that in an deployment of 4 pods utmost 5 pods can be used during the update and at least 3 pods should be made available during the rolling update.

In general **maxSurge** parameter can be considered to be controlling the number of new pods that needs to be created and **maxUnavailable** parameter can be considered to be controlling the number of old pods that can be deleted. Follow this [blog](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/kubernetes-deployments-rolling-update-configuration#:%7E:text=revision%3D1-,Kubernetes%20Rolling%20Updates,-One%20of%20the) written by Keilan Jackson for more information on kubernetes rolling updates.

**Additionally, to ensure there are no downtime/outages during app updates or by Kubernetes nodes auto scale/auto maintenance process, is config replicas must >= 2 mandatory?**

When performing a rolling update the existing replicas will get replaced one-by-one with the new pods, having 2 or more than two replicas will assist you in achieving redundancy when things go in a different way. Hence at least two replicas are required for maintaining the service up while performing the rolling update.